# Google Geocode returns local language even though I request English

Tags: google-api, geocode

I am trying to use the geocode to resolve an address I have. The address I have is..

**Soi 72, Songkhla, Thailand**

and I am making the follow request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Soi%C2%A072%2C%C2%A0Songkhla%2C%C2%A0Thailand%20&sensor=false&language=en

(with my key of course, but I have left that out here.)

and get the following results for the states and country:

```
<address_component>
    <long_name>Amphoe Hat Yai</long_name>
    <short_name>อ.หาดใหญ่</short_name>
    <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
    <type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
    <long_name>Chang Wat Songkhla</long_name>
    <short_name>จ.สงขลา</short_name>
    <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
    <type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
    <long_name>Thailand</long_name>
    <short_name>TH</short_name>
    <type>country</type>
    <type>political</type>
</address_component>
```

Why is the short name in the local language Thai but the long name is in English? How do I force everything into English?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://geocode.xyz/Soi%2072,%20Songkhla,%20Thailand

- Thailand x,y z: 7.05530,100.51575
- Songkhla, TH Thailand » 90110 » Confidence Score: 0.80
  90110 Songkhla,TH